# Замена результата выполнения метода в производных классах

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте уважаемые пользователи. Есть метод в базовом классе, который я хотел бы использовать во всех наследниках.

**Базовый класс:**

```
TRootClass = class
public
   function ToJsonString: string;
   class function FromJsonString(const AJsonString: string): TRootClass;
end;
```

**Наследник:**

```
TBuilding = class(TRootClass)
private
  FId: integer;
  FName: string;
  FAdress: string;
  FAdmin: string;
public
 class function FromJsonString(const AJsonString: string): TBuilding;
 property id: integer read GetId write FId;
 property Name: string read GetName write FName;
 property Adress: string read GetAdress write FAdress;
 property Admin: string read GetAdmin write FAdmin;
```

Собственно метод FromJsonString и хочется использовать во всех дочерних классах, но возник у меня такой вопрос: В данном случае получается что я просто перекрываю метод с таким же названием, однако что будет в случае если я сделаю в базовом классе так:

```
class function FromJsonString(const AJsonString: string): TRootClass; dynamic; abstract;
```

Вообще есть ли в этом смысл? Может ли метод из базового класса изменять свое поведение (например возвращать другой тип данных) в производных классах и при этом же быть абстрактным?

p.s Прошу тапками не кидать, сложно дается ООП и все что с ним связанно

Comment: http://www.delphibasics.ru/Override.php
мб поможет

Comment: @Yuki с данным параметром в дочернем классе я должен буду объявить эту функцию с возвращаемым значением таким же как в родительском иначе компилятор ругается на то что "Объявление "FromJsonString" отличается от предыдущего объявления" , а мне как раз таки его необходимо изменить. Вот тут и возникает вопрос, а в ту ли я сторону думаю или мне просто надо перекрывать метод и не загоняться с абстрактным.

Comment: В базовом классе объявляете метод как `virtual`/`dynamic`, в дочернем пишите `override` и свою имплементацию. При желании, через `inherited` можно дёрнуть метод базового из дочернего. Если же нужно изменить количество/типы параметров в дочернем классе, то тут приходит на помощь `reintroduce`.

Comment: @zed правильно ли я понимаю что в базовом будет так:
`class function FromJsonString(const AJsonString: string): TRootClass; virtual; abstract;`
А в дочернем
`class function FromJsonString(const AJsonString: string): TBuilding; reintroduce;`

Comment: Мне просто честно больше интересно есть ли вообще смысл в том что я делаю, или все таки перекрыть метод самый оптимальный вариант (затенить)

Comment: Да, правильно понимаете. Любой метод, который планируется переопределять в дочернем классе, следует делать виртуальным в базовом (будет он абстрактным или нет, зависит от конкретной ситуации). Так вы явно прописываете свои намерения. В дочернем уже выбираете использовать `override` (если сигнатура метода не изменяется) или `reintroduce`, если изменяется. Так в коде будет прослеживаться архитектура и взаимодействие классов.

Comment: Поменять тип возвращаемого результата в переопределённом методе вы не сможете (без `reintroduce`, но тогда половина смысла переопределения теряется), поэтому имеет смысл везде объявить его как `: TRootClass`, а потом просто использовать приведение типа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как было сказано в комментариях выше @zed и @Akekcvp то есть два варианта решения.
В моем случае на текущий момент есть смысл в базовом классе определить метод как:

```
class function FromJsonString(const AJsonString: string): TRootClass; virtual; abstract;
```

А в дочернем:

```
class function FromJsonString(const AJsonString: string): TBuilding; reintroduce;
```

В целом как указал @Akekcvp - можно использовать приведение типа, но на текущий момент считаю использование reintroduce более подходящим способом.